# SQL to get default schema of some database in Netezza?

Tags: sql, database, netezza

We can change the default schema of a database using alter command. Is there some SQL command to get default schema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check this via the _V_DATABASE view.

```
TESTDB.ADMIN(ADMIN)=> select database, defschema from _v_database where database='TESTDB';
 DATABASE | DEFSCHEMA
----------+-----------
 TESTDB   | ADMIN
(1 row)
```